# How to create a list of markers on a Google Map

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-engine

When I've used the Google Maps Engine to create custom maps for my clients, a panel (layer?) showing a list of my markers has always appeared in the top left corner. In this panel, you're able to turn all of your markers on/off and switch the base map used. Is there a way to create this kind of panel/layer using Google Maps API v3?

I've already looked through every code sample there is in the official documentation and haven't found anything that creates this automatically. I think I could do this manually using layers, but I'm hoping there's a better method I've missed. I don't have any code samples to post because there's nothing wrong with my code as it is now. I'm hoping someone has a snippet they could share.

The map on this site's homepage has an example of the panel I'm talking about and trying to recreate using API v3 - http://www.servesacramento.com/

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  I'd recommend reading [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  In the context of reading your question I have no idea what a panel is, there is no HTML element called panel (I am aware of).  Without a small example of what you are trying to do, it appears you are only asking us for a code example.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't know what the proper term for what I'm trying to create is, so I used "panel." I've added a URL of a website that has an example of what I'm trying to do. Hopefully that helps.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly how it's done on that particular site, but google has an example with an interactive div above the map that modifies an overlay.  The Hide and Show appear to be similar to what you want in terms of *controls* that appear over the map.  [Google Example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/overlay-hideshow).

Comment: I'm not sure who voted my question down, but I don't understand why it was. I updated my question to include an example of what I was trying to create. I came here after looking through every code sample in the API v3 documentation. I don't think I violated any of the pointers on the "How do I ask a good question?" article. What did I do wrong? What more could/should I have done? Please let me know so I can ask a better question next time. Thank you for your time.

Comment: I didn't down-vote, what you are trying to accomplish seems reasonable, but I did voet to close for lack of any code.  The `How do I ask a good question?` is pretty clear in the *Help others reproduce the problem* that you should (guildline) *Include just enough code to allow others to reproduce the problem*.  External links to *this is what I want* without what appears to be any attempt at it yourself (no code examples) is typically frowned upon.

Comment: That all makes sense and I do try to follow the guidelines, but there isn't any relevant code to post. My map works perfectly, just without this feature I'm trying to add. There isn't a problem to reproduce. My code would have just been 117 lines of clutter in my question. I guess I should have said I've already looked through all the code examples in the official documentation and couldn't find solutions there or anywhere else. I'll keep that in mind next time. Is there a more appropriate forum for questions without code samples?

Answer (score 1):

That site isn't using the Google Maps API to create that map and the list of 'markers'.  They're embedding a map directly into their page:

```
<div id="map">
    <h2><span><span>What's happening in my area</span></span></h2>
    <iframe src="https://mapsengine.google.com/map/u/1/embed?mid=z4eR93kMJ6J4.kSQlAEQDX90Q" width="100%" height="500" frameborder="0"></iframe>
</div>
```

You probably want to start here to create your own similar map that you can embed into your website:
https://mapsengine.google.com/map/

Comment: Thank you for your reply. However, my client's needs necessitate using API v3. I'm hoping there's a way to recreate that list of markers in that environment. If there's not a setting I'm simply missing in the API, direction for how to create it manually would be helpful.

Comment: assuming you have a list of places with coordinates, names etc, that you're creating markers with.  you'd need to loop over those to create a simple HTML div or list with those place names, that you could position with CSS over your map (assuming that's a requirement of your client).  You'd also want to attach an event listener for when users click on the place names in that list, which triggers a click event on the equivalent marker (assuming you already have a click event which centres the map and opens an infowindow etc).